# whileループの後のprintがSyntaxErrorになる

Tags: python, python3

表記の件について以下のコードでエラーが出ます。
ご教授ください。

【コード】

```
>>> while x>0:
...     print("{}".format(x))
...     x-=1
... print("happy new year")
```

【エラー】

```
File "<stdin>", line 4
    print("happy new year!")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

【実行させたいプログラム】

x>0がTrueに評価される間コードの実行を繰り返し、x-1を続け、x>0がFalseになったらHappy New Yearを出力するようにしたい。(以下イメージ)

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Happy New Year !
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 対話モードの都合上、入力できないコードがあります

質問のコードに構文の間違いはありません。これをファイルに保存して実行しても、構文エラーにはなりません。
ただし、Pythonインタープリタの[対話モード](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.6/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode)の場合は入力する端から実行するという都合上、どうしても受け付けられないコードがあります。例えばこの質問のように、ブロック文の直後に空行をはさまずに次の文を入力する、というコードは受け付けられません。

#### 対話モードではブロック文の後に空行が必要

対話モードで左側に `...` が出ている時は、文字列やブロック文が前の行から継続している（と判断されている）と思って下さい。
最後の`print("happy new year")`は`while`文の一部ではありませんので、左が`...`のうちは入力せず、空行を入れて`>>>`になってから入力します。

```
>>> x = 5
>>> while x > 0:
...     print("{}".format(x))
...     x-=1
... 
5
4
3
2
1
>>> print("happy new year")
happy new year
>>>
```

参考（英語の類似質問）: [Python Syntax Errors with Python Anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46016327/4368502)

Comment: 丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。ちゃんと理解できました。